# How to keep accented characters with Ruby Shoes?

Tags: ruby, character, diacritics, shoes

With Ruby Shoes, if I do this very simple test:

```
Shoes.app :width => 400, :height => 500 do
    para "testé"
end
```

then it works and displays "testé".

However if I try to do the sme via a class I get an error.

Main file skrolk.shoes:

```
require_relative './headerAjout.rb'

Shoes.app :width => 400, :height => 500
```

Included file headerAjout.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class HeaderAjout < Shoes
    url '/', :index

    def index
        para "testé"
    end
end
```

Error is "invalid multibyte character (UTF-8)".
My Notepad++ is well set to edit in UTF-8.

Any clue please?

Regards,
Dassadar

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on both shoes 4 (https://github.com/shoes/shoes4) and shoes 3.2 9http://shoesrb.com/downloads/) and both run fine.

So it's either fixed in those versions or something platform specific :)